# Redirect to an Area Without Affecting Url in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Is it possible to redirect an MVC3 request to an area route without using a 301/302 redirect after an initial redirection? Let me explain what I want as that sounds complicated even to me.

Basic flow:

1. Request: http://somedomain.com/?ContextId=00001
2. Redirect

   - Serve content from area 01; controller home; action index
   - ContextId query string entry removed from url

So the end result is that all requests to http://somdomain.com after the initial ContextId is set will make use of the area until such a time when a new ContextId is specified.

I can use an `IHttpModule` to capture the query string and then set some value in session for subsequent requests but then I need to issue a `RedirectToXXXX()` call to do the redirect. This will produce a URL with the area included and then I need to identify such "mapped" requests in the future to prevent redirect loops. Euwwww.

I've looked at custom route constraints but routing happens so early in the pipeline that there is no session available which makes it difficult to "know" if the route the constraint is attached to is the one I want. Especially as I don't want the area included in the requesting URL at this stage.

Is this possible? Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Comment: Could you use cookies in your route constraints?

Comment: just testing using cookies now. Not sure it will be suitable for our final solution though. Thanks for the suggestion - will report back with findings.

Comment: @tvanfosson seems cookies are acceptable and they worked nicely within a RouteConstraint. Had a slight niggle with URLs 404ing because of missing namespace in the Route map. Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll give it a tick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the context in a cookie and use the cookie value in the RouteConstraint to force a match to the proper area.